# BadZipFile error confusion with Python zipfile library

Tags: python, pandas, pywin32, temporary-files, python-zipfile

I wrote the functions below in an attempt to extract tabular data from emailed zip file attachments and dump the contents to a pandas data frame. I used temp files to try to be efficient with resource management.

```
def isexcel(file):
    #evaluates file path and return true if excel file. otherwise returns false
    extension = os.path.splitext(file.filename)[1]
    if extension in ['.xls','.xlsx','.xlsm','.xlsb','.odf','.odt','.ods']:
        return True 
    else: 
        return False

def zipattach_to_dfs(attachment, extract_fn=None):
    #evaluates zip file attachments and returns dictionary with file name as key and dataframes as values
    df_objects = {}
    with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp:
        attachment.SaveAsFile(tmp.name)
        zf = ZipFile(tmp)
        for file in zf.infolist():
            key = (f'{file.filename} ({"-".join(map(str, file.date_time[:3]))})')
            if isexcel(file) ==True:
                temp_df = pd.read_excel(zf.open(file.filename), header=None)
                df_objects.update({key:temp_df})
            elif file.filename.endswith(".csv"):
                temp_df = pd.read_csv(zf.open(file.filename), header=None)
                df_objects.update({key:temp_df})
            else:
                raise NotImplementedError('Unexpected filetype: '+str(file.filename))
    return (df_objects)
```

While it seemed to work before, I'm now getting the error "BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" when I tested the below subroutine with a zip file I sent myself that contains a .csv and .xlsx.

```
try:
    for message in messages: 
        print(message.subject)
        attachments = message.attachments
        for attachment in attachments:
            dfs.update(zipattach_to_dfs(attachment))
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

Can anyone tell me if they know what's causing this? My test file is certainly a zipfile, so I'm not sure why this is happening. Hoping someone else here has experience this situation before. I'm guessing the error is related to the temporary file, but I'm not sure.

The traceback is below, if that helps here.

```
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18068\1217034069.py in <module>
     36             dfs.update(zipattach_to_dfs(attachment))
     37 except Exception as e:
---> 38     raise e
     39 print(dfs)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18068\1217034069.py in <module>
     34         attachments = message.attachments
     35         for attachment in attachments:
---> 36             dfs.update(zipattach_to_dfs(attachment))
     37 except Exception as e:
     38     raise e

~\Analytics_Functions.py in zipattach_to_dfs(attachment, extract_fn)
     26     with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp:
     27         attachment.SaveAsFile(tmp.name)
---> 28         zf = ZipFile(tmp)
     29         for file in zf.infolist():
     30             key = (f'{file.filename} ({"-".join(map(str, file.date_time[:3]))})')

~\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel, strict_timestamps)
   1264         try:
   1265             if mode == 'r':
-> 1266                 self._RealGetContents()
   1267             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1268                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

~\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1331             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1332         if not endrec:
-> 1333             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1334         if self.debug > 1:
   1335             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: Try to store the file(s) received as attachment permanently. Then you can examine it with another zip tool and maybe with a hex viewer to find out what it is.

Comment: What's even more perplexing is that I looped through each file and called zipfile.testzip() to try to return any bad zip files. it returns None for every file passed to it.

Comment: it's an issue with xls files in the zip folder